# Why cant I use multiple (selected ) checkbox to attach a relation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a File model and User model. These two are related by many to many relation like:

```
//File model
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
        ->withTimestamps();
}

//User model
public function files(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(File::class);
}
```

I am using a form with checkboxes

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="users[]">
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="users[]">
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="users[]">
<input value="4" type="checkbox" name="users[]">
```

I wan't to attach selected user ids to the file model but it doesnt work. this is my method.

```
$file = File::find(1);
$file->users()->attach( $request->users )
```

But it records only one (the first) user to the intermediate table. It works when I manually type

```
$file->users()->attach( [1,2,3] )
```

but somehow the $request->users don't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You may need to loop through `$request->users` as it will come in as `[0=>1,1=>2,2=>3]` and from the docs it looks like `attach()` only accepts non-key/value arrays.

Comment: @Press, you can't have an array without keys. The above method by the OP should work.

Comment: @SteveBauman you're right, whoops. Then the only thing I can think of is the array is empty/null.

Comment: @Skeletor, can you verify that you're actually receiving data from your form? In your controller, try `dd($request->users)`

Comment: @SteveBauman I did a dd($request->users) and the result is  "1,2,3"

Comment: @SteveBauman I did a dd( gettype($request->users) ) too and the result is "string"

Comment: Does `$request->get('users')` work? It should be an array

Comment: @nXu nope still the same, only the firs character was attached. Yes I think it should be an array too. but why is it an string then?

Comment: Isn't the request method GET accidentally?

Comment: I used collective form to create the textboxes. I changed it to manually form but still the same.

Comment: Yea but what's the request method?

Comment: @nXu actually its POST

Comment: thank you all guys. I found the problem. I am using a form but there was an ajax call instead the form itself. And jq was passing it as an string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I was using a ajax call to get the values from the form. That was totally out of my scope but (thx to everyone) discussing this made me aware of it. So I solved it with an explode().

```
$file->users()->attach( explode(',', $request->users);
```